# How to connect 2 docker hosts without using a swarm

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I have a setup with 3 PCs. 2 hosts A and B on the same local network 192.168.0.0/24 have docker installed and can spawn containers. Another computer C is also on the network 192.168.0.0/24. A and B are running containers and D is the gateway.

The part of the network that matters is like:

- A (192.168.0.6): running container_a (172.28.6.31)
- B (192.168.0.11): running container_b (172.28.5.31)
- C (192.168.0.12) - not running docker.
- D (192.168.0.1) - gateway to outside world.

How do connect them so that container_a to container_b and C can all connect in the same manner ?

Docker suggests using a swarm and an overlay, however it was not clear to me how computer C would access container_a and container_b by IP directly. I can't forward ports for this because it is ROS and I need to have access to multiple ports directly.

TESTs: I am not sure exactly what are the requirements for ROS, but I would say that if you can do:

```
$ ssh container_a
$ ssh container_b
$ ssh C
```

On every on every node, then it will probably work. Don't mind the name resolution, if they are accessible by IP then it is solved.

```
$ ssh 172.28.6.31
$ ssh 172.28.5.31
$ ssh 192.168.0.12
```

---

The way I partially solved this was by setting a bridge in A (like 172.28.5.0/24), another bridge in B (like 172.28.6.0/24) and setting up the routing table manually, on each host as well as the forwarding rules.

This is fine, but I wish I could use something like a router for this, not to have to change the routing tables on every host, each time I add or remove a docker host.

---

What I've tried:

I am positive that I can solve this if I can have a privileged container with a valid external IP on 192.168.0.0/24. Then I just need to set this as a gateway for everything on 172.28.0.0/16, while keeping the rule for 172.28.5.0/24 pointing to A (or 172.28.6.0/24 pointing to B). The container needs to be privileged so we can change its routing table, and there are security issues here, but I will not think about them now.

From https://forums.docker.com/t/public-accessible-ip-in-container-like-bridge-network-in-virtualbox/3668/6

I "adapted" into my case as:

```
sudo ip addr del 192.168.0.6/24 dev eno1

docker network create \
 --driver=bridge \
 --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 \
 --gateway=192.168.0.6 \
 --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="docker1" \
 shared_nw

sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.6/24 dev eno1

sudo brctl addif docker1 eno1
```

Then I created my makeshift router:

```
docker run --name my_router \
 --net=shared_nw \
 --privileged \
 --ip=192.168.0.22 -itd \
 alpine /bin/sh

docker attach my_router
```

Then inside my_router:

```
route add default gw 192.168.0.1

route add -net 172.28.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.11

route add -net 172.28.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.6
```

This feels like it is almost the answer, but there were so many issues with setting the correct routes that I couldn't fix and forwarding not working that I believe I must have made some mistake. I presume there is a simple solution with ipvlan or macvlan or overlays, but I really couldn't figure out by myself.

---

Another attempt with ipvlan that also seems close:

```
docker network create -d ipvlan --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 -o parent=eno1 shared_nw
docker run --name my_router --net=shared_nw --privileged --ip=192.168.0.22 -idt alpine

docker attach my_router
```

Inside my_router define the routes:

```
route add -net 172.28.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.6
route add -net 172.28.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.11
```

Configure my hosts (A,B,C) to use this router for the docker net:

```
sudo route add -net 172.28.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.0.22
```

And setup forwarding on the ones that host docker containers (A,B):

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using traditional tools is tedious and complex from a configuration management point of view indeed. Have you considered to use an overlay network solution?

Comment: I've tried. I could not get an overlay working without a swarm and could not get a swarm the outside world to connect directly to a machine within a swarm. If you know how to do it, please answer :)

Comment: Have you tried an overlay network solution like WeaveNet? Indeed, Docker has an integrated overlay network but it depends on Swarm.

N.B. Check out this Web page: https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/install/plugin/plugin-how-it-works/.

Comment: I can't use the swarm because ROS doesn't work with only port forwarding. ROS manages socket addresses itself and in a way competes with what a docker swarm does

Comment: So far adapting this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1014523/creating-a-docker-macvlan-network-with-different-gateway-than-subnet/1014568 is the closest I could get to it working, but I think I maybe messed it up with a circular route or something because I can't get full connectivity between the host and the hosted container.

Comment: You are trying to implement an underlay networking connectivity between your docker hosts. This is a delicate configuration and because of this I recommended an overlay network between your standalone docker hosts. I saw that somebody deployed ROS with WeaveNet plug-in in Kubernetes and this option is similar in behavior to what you are trying to achieve but without a software container orchestrator.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will check it out.